# Automorphism group of the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, automorphism-group

Consider ``the'' projective line over the integers (which can come in various guises). I have two questions:

- What is the scheme-theoretic automorphism group of the scheme $\texttt{Proj}(\mathbb{Z}[x, y])$ ?
- What is the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})$ seen as a projective line over a ring (with typical coordinates, similar to the vector-spacial definition) ?

Comment: Please don't write $\mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Z})$ for the scheme. (It usually denotes the set of $\mathbb{Z}$-valued points of $\mathbb{P}^1$.)

Comment: @reuns: oops, a typo, I'll change it right away.

Comment: @ZhenLin: agreed, I will edit the question.